# Would have made it

Tags: tense

Plot: [Cinder](http://readfictions.com/chapter/116124/the-lunar-chronicles-1-cinder-marissa-meyer/cinder-page-41) had been struggling for reaching the palace.

> She **would have made it**, she thought, as the palace came into view,
>   towering over the city atop its jagged cliff.

I am aware of "would have done" can indicate subjunctive mood which means should could have made it (but might be failed.)

However, I guess this "would have made it" means "she almost made it" because the palace was just in front of her.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sentence needs to be considered in the larger context of the novel to be fully understood. Cinder intends to run away from the city. Then she receives news that she has to share with the Prince, so she decides to go to the ball instead.

The "would have done" is subjunctive because it's in reference to her hypothetical plan to escape (as is made clearer in the next sentence: "She would have been nearing the city limits by now"), not her actual journey to the palace.

Comment: Oh, I see it in an astonished way, Great! Thanks!